# Is there a UV maps limit?

Tags: uv

Using the properties panel I can add, with "+"  button, only eight UV maps. Is it possible to have more than 8 of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's limited to 8. Explanations on [devtalk.blender.org](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/origin-of-uv-map-limit-in-blender/1014).

Note that using multiple UV maps isn't quite recommended, it's memory heavy, not every software supports more than 8 UVs (some don't even go up to 8), there are usually tons of ways to do without extra UV sets,...

Comment: I managed to hit the UV limit cap because I was using UV maps to place individual decals onto a model and position them how I want individually as part of a single material (Which I was going to then later bake down to a single texture for a game asset which would have one UV). I'd be interested to know what alternate approaches would be suggested.